# Displaying ± symbol in Java

Tags: java, string, special-characters

How to get the character `±` in a string?

Comment: Just paste it in? How did you get it into your StackOverflow question?

Comment: Have you tried just putting that symbol in the string? If that doesn't work, try figuring out the Unicode value of that character and put it in using \uXXXX.

Comment: @Matt, remi, robbrit: The problem with just putting the symbol in a literal string is that you will then depend on the platform encoding. Try to compile the same source file with literals strings containing non-ASCII characters in Windows and Linux and things will get funny.

Comment: At first I also thought I was an incomplete question but then I read the tag. And for the first time tag was actually the part of question.

Comment: @Grodriguez: If the java source file is property encoded in UTF8/UTF16 or Unicode it will work. Clearly using an 8 bit encoding such as latin1 whatever will not.

Comment: That's why I say that you would depend on the encoding. If you use a Unicode escape (`\u00B1`), then that becomes a non-issue.

Comment: Hi all, Thank you very much for all your support.....

Comment: @codymanix - man javac tells me `If -encoding is not specified, the platform default converter is used.` Some crazy platforms might not use unicode as default. `\uxxxx` is the only sane way.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use Unicode: `\u00B1`:

```
System.out.println("Hello \u00B1 world");
```

Prints:

```
Hello ± world
```

Comment: And if ever you don't know the Unicode code point for something, Google does.  "unicode plus minus" --> http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/b1/index.htm

Comment: @Alan Krueger: Googling "unicode plus minus" is a silly advice. It ain't very useful when you don't know the name of the character you're looking at. Like this one, for example, how would you Google it? '  ҉'.  That's when a cut/paste and Un*x commands like *hexdump* and *file* are useful ;)   Now of course you can cut/paste that character in Google and you'll find out, but suggesting to search for such characters using text like "unicode plus minus" just doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @Webinator You can come up with counter-examples, but for someone who doesn't know where to look it's remarkably effective.

Answer (score 6):

Put this into your string: `\u00B1`

[Source](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/b1/index.htm)

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Linux system you can find hex codes for almost all the symbol using man pages iso_8859-1(7), iso_8859-10(7), iso_8859-13(7), iso_8859-14(7), iso_8859-15(7), iso_8859-16(7), iso_8859-2(7), iso_8859-3(7), iso_8859-4(7), iso_8859-5(7), iso_8859-6(7), iso_8859-7(7), iso_8859-8(7), iso_8859-9(7). There you will find that the hex code for ± is B1. There!! you have it now.

Answer (score 0):

*(Prerequisite: source file must be properly encoded in utf8/utf16/unicode)*

Nothing simpler than that:

```
string s = "±";
```

Note that java strings and identifiers are always encoded in utf16, so this is natively supported.

Comment: Since I can't always guarantee what happens to the source after it's been written, and file systems don't generally treat character encoding as a first-class attribute of the file, if it's outside Latin-1 I typically use a Unicode escape.  It seems safer that way.

Comment: Prerequisite? You can specify the encoding with javac? `javac -encoding Cp1252` for example. (I would not recommend this...)

Comment: but people having UTF-8 or UTF-16 *.java* source file should be shot!  Here we have developers on Windows, Linux and OS X **AND** our build script enforces that *every single .java file* is ASCII-only.  Why?  Experience.  Plain and simple.

Comment: @Webinator: no, people using tools that don't support UTF-8 should be shot. Why? Experience. Plain and simple.